# How to delete rows that have up to 6 variables that are nont NA in R

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics

Hello so I want to delete some rows from a data frame. In the dataframe 5 of the variables have value always. And the others may have or have NA value. So I want to keep only the rows that Have at least 6 variables with value.

I tried using dropna(df, thresh=6) but this I think works only in python and I couldnt find the syntax for the R.

Thank you

Comment: try `df[!is.na(df[,6])]`

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
my_df[rowSums(!is.na(my_df)) >= 6, ]
```

The explanation:

`is.na(my_df)`
Tests which cells in `my_df` are `NA`s and returns a logical matrix with dimensions the same as those of `my_df` (the symbol `!` is for the negation),

`rowSums(!is.na(my_df))` will then return the number of non-`NA` values in each row in `my_df`,

eventually `rowSums(!is.na(my_df)) >= 6` will be a logical vector indicating which rows have at least 6 non-`NA` values, and this will be the mask with which we filter the rows of the dataframe

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this work please? Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry! I should've done that. Please see the edited answer

Comment: Great you explained that very well thank you again :)

Comment: Sure! no problem. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: where do I accept?